# javafx high cpu usage intel 610/620

Tags: java, performance, javafx, charts, intel

Do you also notice latencies or high CPU consumption in JDK 11 and 14 for a JavaFX app if we use integrated graphics cards intel UHD 610/620 to in my case a core i3 8145u.

The same code (admittedly not optimized and a bit long to put it here) starts without problem on an atom pc and / or a core i5 but on a core i3 8145u and its 610/620 graphics card after a while that saturates the cpu.
It is a graph (linechart) which displays values every second, after 3 hours the CPU sees its consumption go from 20% to 90-100%.
I have already tried changing the jvm settings, prism.order settings etc but I still have the phenomenon.

Does anyone have an explanation to this? or a research axis to advise me?

Comment: Have you tried something like VirtualVM to see what is going on? Maybe you have a memory leak so that after a while your CPU gets busy with garbage collection.

Comment: i use liberica mission control, alternative to virtualVM, i can huge use of garbage. I use G1GC but i don't know what i have to change to reduce cpu usage, i'm a newbie on VM settings and i don't which parameters can i use with jdk14 or later, maybe some are deprecated or useless now

Comment: In a first attempt you can allow your VM to use more memory. (See docs for exact option.) Garbage as such is not the problem as long as it can be released. If however you are producing garbage which cannot be released you have to find out in your code why this is the case. There is no magic option to fix your code.